# web view not found, no such window: target window already closed

Tags: java, selenium, runtime-error

I am running an automation test using selenium and get the following error -

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
>   from unknown error: web view not found

I have searched other questions on the topic but in this case, the window handle doesn't switch, no new window is opened, and the base window is still there.
Result: It prints the values of the column names twice and then shows the error.

Code is as follows:

```
DiseSearchtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(SearchResulttableLocator));

List<WebElement> rows=DiseSearchtable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int rnum=0;rnum<rows.size();rnum++) {
    List<WebElement>columns=rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
    System.out.println("Number of columns:"+columns.size());
    for(int cnum=0;cnum<columns.size();cnum++) {
        System.out.println(columns.get(cnum).getText());
    }
}
```

> trace -  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window:
>   target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found
>   (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command
>   duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code? How do you setup your test, which driver, and so on. And can you post the complete stack? Normally NoSuchWindowException is not the root cause.

Comment: see this :[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980299/chromedriver-exception-reporting-target-window-already-closed-in-headless-mode)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this error occurs if you don't refresh the page for a while. Just put a timer to refresh every hour and it should be good.

Also possibly that the list you were looping through may be refreshing while it's going through then when you try to execute something on it's elements it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some more code for clarification. Better, you should check the version of selenium and browser, whether they are compatible with one another. Secondly, try to look over the login and setup once again.

Answer (score 0):

1. you question is too sample to answer.
2. There also has an answer here [ChromeDriver exception reporting “target window already closed” in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980299/chromedriver-exception-reporting-target-window-already-closed-in-headless-mode)
3. & the discussion is useful too, [discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-matt-w](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169858/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-matt-w)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.